# Is it risky to have trailing commas in .tfvars or auto.tfvars files?

Tags: arrays, json, amazon-web-services, syntax, terraform

I see that the [official Terraform documentation](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/variables) shows that trailing commas in arrays are okay in `.tfvars` files. Their example:

```
availability_zone_names = [
  "us-east-1a",
  "us-west-1c",
]
```

However, `.tfvars.json` files get parsed as `JSON` so I assume they wouldn't allow this. Therefore, is it bad practice to have trailing commmas in a `.tfvars` or `.auto.tfvars` file? Is there any scenario where an `auto.tfvars` file would somehow need to be converted into a `.tfvars.json` file behind the scenes (or explicitely) and this could cause problems?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend including a trailing comma because it helps maintain git blame logs.

Without a trailing comma, whenever a new item is added, the blame for the previous item is lost.

##### Example:

First commit: `added project 'X' with id 2222`

```
project_ids = [
  2222 // Blame: added project 'X' with id 2222
]
```

Then you add another project with commit log: `added project 'Y' with id 3333`

```
project_ids = [
  2222, // Blame: added project 'Y' with id 3333
  3333  // Blame: added project 'Y' with id 3333
]
```

This shows that adding the second project corrupts the log for the first project added because adding the comma afterwards changes the `2222` line.

Answer (score 2):

> Therefore, is it bad practice to have trailing commmas in a .tfvars or .auto.tfvars file?

No per se as it won't affect anything, but an extra character is an extra character that could have not been there in the first place.

> Is there any scenario where an `auto.tfvars` file would somehow need to be converted into a `.tfvars.json` file behind the scenes (or explicitly) and this could cause problems?

Not that I'm aware of, but even if so I would assume for Terraform to have its own sanitisation measures in place if they are doing conversions or for it to fail fast & early.

All in all, It's not risky to have trailing commas in `.tfvars` or `auto.tfvars` files.